# How to show a 'Show More' button if there is overflow, and change it to 'Show Less' if clicked (Angular 2)?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm wondering what the best approach to this would be in **Angular 2**.  The button should only appear if there is overflow on a div, and if it's clicked, it should change to 'Show Less', and show less if clicked.

Is it best to create a toggling function in the component?

Would it be better to create two buttons - one for each - and use ngShow/ngHide?

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of a toggle button here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" 
        (click)="toggleImage()">
        {{showImage ? "Hide" : "Show"}} Poster
</button>
```

This is tied to a showImage Boolean property. However, I'm not sure how you would set that property based on whether there is an overflow on a div?